# Does $\Pr[|X|\leq x] \geq p \implies \Pr[X\leq x] \geq p$ hold?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable, $x$ be a real number, $p \in [0,1]$.

Does the following implication hold?

$\Pr[|X|\leq x] \geq p \implies \Pr[X\leq x] \geq p$

I am looking at a proof where this seems to be used.

Is this based on "equivalence of events" or something like that?

But $\Pr[|X|\leq x] = \Pr[ -x \leq X\leq x]$, and my random variable $X$ is not constrained to be only positive ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to say what @grand_chat said is this: notice that $[-x,x]\subset (-\infty ,x]$ and because $\Pr$ is a (positive) measure defined by
$$
\Pr[X\in A]:=\Pr(\{\omega\in \Omega :X(\omega)\in A\})\tag1
$$
then we have that
$$
A\subset B\implies \Pr[X\in A]\leqslant \Pr[X\in B]\tag2
$$
because any (positive) measure is an increasing function, and so
$$
\Pr[|X|\leqslant x]\leqslant \Pr[X\leqslant x]\tag3
$$
what imply the result that you want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

It holds, because the event $|X|\le x$ *implies* the event $X\le x$. It follows that
$
P(|X|\le x)\le P(X\le x)
$.